# Allow a Vue Library accept scss to put into the vue.config.js file

Tags: vue.js, webpack, sass, vue-cli-3

I am trying to create a Vue.js component library, which will *later* be released on npm for future projects of mine to use it. However, I would like the components to have default scss variables, AKA variables marked with the !default flag. Then, whenever I use the component library in a new project I would like to have the ability for the component library to use a unique scss file which may contain overwrites to the scss variables.

I know to add scss file to the libraries vue.config.js file (I am using vue-cli 3) for each component to pull in that file. However, I cannot figure out how to have vue's configuration to use both the default varaiables file and a project's variables file to "merge" the scss variables. This may be more of a webpack question than a vue question.